# checkbox checked but row will not showing in Edit Mode(actionFunction not working)

Tags: rerender, actionfunction, rendered, inputcheckboxes

ActionFuntion not working what i miss can you please tell

class code:

```
public class EditContact_controller{
    public List<wrapperClass> wrapClassList{get;set;}
    public List<contact> conList{get;set;}
    public wrapperClass wc{get;set;}

    public EditContact_controller(){
        wrapClassList = new List<wrapperClass>();
        conList = new List<Contact>();
        conList = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, email, Phone FROM Contact LIMIT 10];
        For(Contact co : conList){
            wc = new wrapperClass();
            wc.flag = false;
            wc.conWrap = co;
            wrapClassList.add(wc);
        }

    }

    public pagereference updateRecord() {
          Upsert conList;
          return new pageReference('/apex/EditContact').setRedirect(true);   
    }
    public class wrapperClass{
        public boolean flag{get;set;}
        public Contact conWrap{get;set;}

    }
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="EditContact_controller" tabStyle="Contact">
    <apex:form id="frm">
        <apex:sectionHeader title="Contact Records"/>
        <apex:actionFunction name="check" reRender="cont_Table"/>
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
               <apex:commandButton value="Update Record" action="{!updateRecord}" reRender="frm"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <table width = "100%" id="tab">
             <tr>
                 <th> Action </th>
                 <th> First Name </th>
                 <th> Last Name </th>
                 <th> Email </th>
                 <th> Phone </th>
             </tr>

             <apex:repeat value="{!wrapClassList}" var="contactTable" id="cont_Table">
                    <tr>

                        <td> <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!contactTable.flag}" onClick="check();"/> </td>

                        <td> <apex:outputField value="{!contactTable.conWrap.FirstName}" rendered="{!(!contactTable.flag)}" /> 
                             <apex:inputField value="{!contactTable.conWrap.FirstName}" rendered="{!contactTable.flag}" />   
                        </td>

                        <td> <apex:outputField value="{!contactTable.conWrap.LastName}" rendered="{!(!contactTable.flag)}"/> 
                             <apex:inputField value="{!contactTable.conWrap.LastName}" rendered="{!contactTable.flag}"/>                       
                        </td>

                        <td> <apex:outputField value="{!contactTable.conWrap.email}" rendered="{!(!contactTable.flag)}"/>
                             <apex:inputField value="{!contactTable.conWrap.email}" rendered="{!contactTable.flag}"/>                       
                         </td>

                        <td> <apex:outputField value="{!contactTable.conWrap.phone}" rendered="{!(!contactTable.flag)}"/>
                             <apex:inputField value="{!contactTable.conWrap.phone}" rendered="{!contactTable.flag}"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
              </apex:repeat>
            </table>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Try removing 'return false' from onclick

Comment: i have removed now checkbox is checked but row will now appear in editmode i mean inputField not working

Comment: You have to write some logic to switch the checkboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reRendering to repeat you should use output panel and from actionfunction you should reRender outputpanel. use this it'll work for you.

```
<apex:page controller="EditContact_controller" tabStyle="Contact">
<apex:form id="frm">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Contact Records"/>
    <apex:actionFunction name="check"  reRender="cont_Table"/>
    <apex:pageBlock >

        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
           <apex:commandButton value="Update Record" action="{!updateRecord}" reRender="frm"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:outputPanel id="cont_Table">
        <table width = "100%" id="tab">
             <tr>
                 <th> Action </th>
                 <th> First Name </th>
                 <th> Last Name </th>
                 <th> Email </th>
                 <th> Phone </th>
             </tr>

                    <apex:repeat value="{!wrapClassList}" var="contactTable" >
                        <tr>

                        <td> <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!contactTable.flag}" onClick="check();"/> </td>

                        <td> <apex:outputField value="{!contactTable.conWrap.FirstName}" rendered="{!(!contactTable.flag)}" /> 
                             <apex:inputField value="{!contactTable.conWrap.FirstName}" rendered="{!contactTable.flag}" />   
                            </td>

                            <td> <apex:outputField value="{!contactTable.conWrap.LastName}" rendered="{!(!contactTable.flag)}"/> 
                                 <apex:inputField value="{!contactTable.conWrap.LastName}" rendered="{!contactTable.flag}"/>                       
                            </td>

                            <td> <apex:outputField value="{!contactTable.conWrap.email}" rendered="{!(!contactTable.flag)}"/>
                                 <apex:inputField value="{!contactTable.conWrap.email}" rendered="{!contactTable.flag}"/>                       
                             </td>

                            <td> <apex:outputField value="{!contactTable.conWrap.phone}" rendered="{!(!contactTable.flag)}"/>
                                 <apex:inputField value="{!contactTable.conWrap.phone}" rendered="{!contactTable.flag}"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
            </apex:repeat>

        </table>  
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
```